# Need JQuery or JavaScript to use .contains() with && logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, narrowing

I am attempting to build a simple narrow by filter using given key word buttons on an otherwise static list of items.

The buttons are in an unordered list and when selected get the class ".selected-tag-button" added to them.

The items are divs with class ".item" and get class ".included-item" when they are active. Inside the div is another UL with list items that contain key words that match the text node on the buttons.

Right now it is working, except, instead of using "buttonName" which contains only the key word for the clicked button, I would like to use "buttonArray" which contains an array of all the selected key words.

I assume I will need some kind of function, but I am not sure where to start. If more than one are selected I want the result to be limited to only items that contain ALL of the selected key words. All of the solutions I have been able to figure out will return the divs that contain ANY of the key words in the array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("li.tag-button").on("click", function() {

    // Toggle button
    $(this).toggleClass("selected-tag-button");

    // Remove included-item class from all items
    $(".item" ).removeClass("included-item");

    // Pass the button text into variable
    var buttonName = $(this).text().slice(2);

    // Create array with button text for all active buttons
    var buttonArray = $(".selected-tag-button").map(function() {
      return $(this).text().slice(2);
    }).get();
    console.log(buttonArray);

    // Add included-item class to divs containing the button text
    $('li:contains("' + buttonName + '")').parents().parents().addClass("included-item");

    // If all buttons are inactive, add included-item class to all items
    if ($(".selected-tag-button").length == 0 ) {
      $(".item" ).addClass("included-item");
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: Please clear your question. Put your html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6qavvth8/

```
for(i=0; i<buttonArray.length;i++){
    contains += ':contains("' + buttonArray[i] + '")'; 
}
$('ul' + contains).parents().addClass("included-item");
```

Loop through your button array to build your jquery selector and keep adding :contains()

Comment: That worked with a couple tweaks. Had to fix the i-0 to i=0, define and clear the contains variable outside the loop so each click re-sets it, and change the li to ul, so it accepted all lists that included the set of terms, instead of looking for a single list item that contained them.

Comment: Oh my bad, about the i-0 thing, just a sloppy typo. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification of @bingo's solution. Works perfectly, thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("li.tag-button").on("click", function() {

    // Toggle button
    $(this).toggleClass("selected-tag-button");

    // Remove included-item class from all items
    $(".item" ).removeClass("included-item");

    // Create array with button text for all active buttons
    var buttonArray = $(".selected-tag-button").map(function() {
      return $(this).text().slice(2);
    }).get();

    // Add included-item class to divs containing the button text
    var contains = ""; 
    for(i = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++){
      contains += ':contains("' + buttonArray[i] + '")'; 
    }
    $('ul' + contains).parents().addClass("included-item");    

    // If all buttons are inactive, add included-item class to all items
    if ($(".selected-tag-button").length == 0 ) {
      $(".item" ).addClass("included-item");
    }

  });

});
```